# How to show link only to users in specified group

Tags: organic-groups, users

I have a link and I want to show it only for users which are in group `Pracownik`. I use https://www.drupal.org/project/og and the Drupal version is 7.

How to make a link visible only to one group of users?

Comment: What do you mean by "Link"?

Comment: Please be more specific - is this in a block, form, menu, content field, view, template etc?